# Tab crashes when large file is dragged-and-dropped

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop, crash, filereader

I have set up a simple drag and drop file selector. To pass a dropped file to the server, I am getting its data URL and putting that into an input field. This works with small enough files. When you drop a large file (>300mb in my tests) though, the file name, but not contents will not be read or the (Chrome) tab may even crash completely(!). Why is this? How can I fix this (preferably without XMLHttpRequest2).

```js
function processFile(file) {
 var name = file.name, reader = new FileReader();
 $("form input[name=filename]").val("Processing...");
 reader.onload = function(blob) {
  $("form input[name=blob]").attr("value", blob.target.result);
  $("form input[name=filename]").val(name);
 }
 reader.readAsDataURL(file);
}
$(document).on("dragenter", function(e) {
 e.preventDefault();
}).on("dragover", function(e) {
 e.preventDefault();
 e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.dropEffect = "copy";
}).on("drop", function(e) {
 e.preventDefault();
 var files = (e.dataTransfer || e.originalEvent.dataTransfer).files;
 if (files && files.length > 0) {
  var file = files[0];
  processFile(file);
 }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
 <input type="text" name="blob" />
 <input type="text" name="filename" />
</form>
Drag file here
```

Comment: The contents of a 300mb file is too much for the browser to parse, so it is normal to crash. For that large size of files, i would use file inputs.

Comment: Also you can try uploading file with smaller chunks as described [here](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/)